# How to use OnBehalfOfContentOwner field while using youtube data API insert request?

Tags: go, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Context :

I am trying to upload videos to a youtube channel(Other-Y) linked to a google cloud project(say X).
I am not the owner of the channel. However, I have the manager access. I have client secret keys with me.
Steps followed :

1. Generate refresh token using these gcp secret keys and with my own personal email(this email is linked to the gcp account).I am using oauth credentials.
2. Now, while uploading, the video is getting uploaded to my own personal channel and not to the channel I am managing.

I have read about the OnBehalfOfContentOwner field and am trying to use that.

Questions :

1. Is this upload possible using OnBehalfOfContentOwner field ?
2. If yes, is there a way to know the exact value to be passed here ? Should it be user id of the channel owner in the youtube UI ?

Also, please let me know if there are any specific golang references for the same.

Thanks !

Comment: what you have passed in `OnBehalfOfContentOwner` due to which video got uploaded in your channel? Can you specify it here!

Comment: Well, I wasn't able to use that attribute at all.